# How to open a link in a select box in a new window?

Tags: javascript, select, new-window

How can I open each link in this select box in a new window?

```
<form name="jump">
<select name="menu">
<option value="http://">link</option>
<option value="http://">link</option>
<option value="http://">link</option>
</select>
<input type="button" onClick="location=document.jump.menu.options[document.jump.menu.selectedIndex].value;" value="GO" />
</form>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct function for a new window is [`window.open();`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.open)

```
<form name="jump">
    <select name="menu">
       <option value="http://">link</option>
       <option value="http://">link</option>
       <option value="http://">link</option>
       </select>
       <input type="button" id="button"
       onclick="window.open(document.jump.menu.options[document.jump.menu.selectedIndex].value);" value="GO" />
</form>
```

**Note:** Writing in line javascript can be messy. try separating your javascript from your presentation